# Error checking in a '.read' function in kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

What should a `.read` operation return in a kernel module character device?

I know that `copy_to_user(...)` returns the number of bytes not copied and on success returns 0. I saw examples which make the `read()` function `return -EFAULT` if `copy_to_user(...)` returns anything other than 0.

But then upon success [this](http://derekmolloy.ie/writing-a-linux-kernel-module-part-2-a-character-device/) says to return 0 and [this](http://linux.die.net/lkmpg/x569.html) says to return the number of bytes read. What should be returning?

Also should I check the params of

```
static ssize_t dev_read(struct file *filep, char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset)
```

like checking if `buffer==NULL` or `len == something`? If so, what should I return on a bad condition?

Comment: The cool thing about writing code is you get to define what it does :-) So either behaviour is ok as long as it is well defined. Having said that, the first example given is not standard `read` behaviour. Standard read functions should return the number of bytes read. That first example says "This code has a fixed message size of 256 characters — this will be improved in later articles". And that is perhaps why the writer has implemented `0` on success. Because the size is always fixed. But I would advise sticking with standard `read` behaviour for your code unless you have good reason not to.

Comment: should I at least be returning `return -EFAULT`  from the `read()` function if the `copy_to_user()` returns something other than `0`? I've seen some examples do this and others not. I'm currently reading more into what `-EFAULT` is, but is this a convention?

Comment: Yes it is a convention. So again you don't have to follow it if you have good reason not to but by default you should. If in doubt follow the standard library behavior.  In your case use the `read` man page as the guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.read` operation should return either:

- number of bytes copied into user-provided buffer, or
- negative error code

Additionally, operation should update `*offset` value, so futher reading from the file will return next portion of data.

If driver implementation follows this rules, standard commmands like `cat`, `dd` will interpret result of *read* system call correctly, and, by possibly repeating it, output to the user full "content" of the device.

Normally, correctness of `buffer` parameter is checked in `copy_to_user` call. If this call fails(returns non-zero), -EFAULT is usually returned by `.read`.

`len` argument is rarely checked for errors. Assuming `data_len` to be length of remaing data:

- if `len` < `data_len`, copy first `len` bytes into buffer and return `len`
- if `len` > `data_len`, copy all remaining bytes into buffer and return `data_len`
- if `data_len` or `len` is 0, return 0

Sometimes device's data can be read only by portions of predefined size. In that situation you can check `len` and return -EINVAL in case it has inappropriate value. `buffer` can also being checked for alignment.

---

As for example, where `.read` returns 0 on success, it is correct until device is used by own-written user-space program, which doesn't check actual length of returning data.

Comment: So I looked deeper into `copy_to_user`, and since that calls `access_ok`, the parameter `buffer` won't ever need to be checked by me, correct? Immediately after variable declarations in the function, I check for `filep` and `buffer` `== NULL` and `return -EINVAL` if they are. Does this hurt the program since `buffer` is needlessly(?) being checked by me since it's being checked in `copy_to_user()`?

Comment: You may check anything, but it is just not needed(but doesn't make harm except performance). `buffer == NULL` never passes `access_ok` check (except `len==0` case, when `buffer` is not used), `filep == NULL` is impossible because file should be opened successfully before reading.