# Linux Kernel Module, creating a LIFO device

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to write a simple kernel module (char device) that acts as a memory, a LIFO (stack) to be exact. The current code goes something like this:

```
#include <linux/module.h> 
//and the rest of the includes and defines go here

struct virtual_device{ char data[STACK_SIZE];
}stack;// my stack data is stored in this structure

int device_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp){return 0;}

int device_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp){return 0;}

ssize_t device_write(struct file *filp, const char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *offset){
  ret = copy_from_user(stack.data,buf,count);
  return ret;
}

ssize_t device_read(struct file *filp, char* buf, size_t count, loff_t *offset){
  ret = copy_to_user(buf, stack.data,count);
  return ret; 
}

struct file_operations fops = {
  .open = device_open,
  .write = device_write,
  .read = device_read,
  .release = device_release
};

static int driver_entry( void ){
  //this part of the code is pretty standard, 
  //module initialization , major number generation and so on
}

static void driver_exit( void ){
  //char device deletion, unregister...
}

module_init(driver_entry);
module_exit(driver_exit);
```

After reading a bit about both copy_to_user and copy_from_user functions, my impression is that I can loop them and handle the file pointer so as to change the order in which the device is written. I changed the write function to this:

```
ssize_t device_write(struct file *filp, const char *buf, size_t count,loff_t *offset){
  char *temp;
  int i=1;

  while(i<= count){
    temp = buf + count - i;
    ret = copy_from_user(stack.data,temp,1);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Writing to device");      
    i +=1;
  } 
return ret; 
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to copy from user character by character, from the back to front, hoping that when I read the message, it will be inverted (you know how LIFO reads the from the last entry to the first).

However, the device goes crazy when I try to use it: Even though I wrote to it "hola", the dmesg log shows like 50 "Writing to device" messages, and when I try to read from it all I get is �.
 Can anybody please point out what am I overlooking? Is my attempt too naive?

Comment: Actually, even original implementations of `.read` and `.write` methods are incorrect: `copy_to_user` returns number of bytes which *has not been written*, but `.read` should return number of bytes which **has been written to user space**. See [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33423312/error-checking-a-read-function-in-kernel-module/33426104#33426104) about conventions on values returned by `.read` method. Conventions for `.write` are the same except returning 0 doesn't mean EOF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because u returning the 0 all the time (assuming copy_from_user didn't fail). So VFS think your driver didn't accepted(wrote) anything. And VFS will keep trying to write....
That's why u keep getting "Writing to device" message.

```
while(i<= count){

    temp = buf + count - i;

    ret = copy_from_user(stack.data,temp,1); // ==> U keep writing data to same position -> stack.data[0]

    printk(KERN_INFO "Writing to device");      
    i +=1;
} 


ssize_t device_read(struct file *filp, char* buf, size_t count, loff_t *offset){
  ret = copy_to_user(buf, stack.data,count);//==> U should return whatever u have in "data" instead of use "count" which might be pretty big.
  return ret; 
}
```

Comment: Yes,  you and Tsyvarev have made notice about that. Actually I was confused about what exactly were those callbacks supposed to return. I have made corrections and everything works now. Thanks for the support.