# Char Driver Linux: What is the correct implementation of file_operations read and write? What are the offset checks needs to be made?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to read and write to a char driver. When i use a C program to open the device file and read and write it gives a SEG fault. When I use a cat to the device file it goes to infinite loop.

1) What am I missing, and what is the correct implementation of read and write in file_operations?

2) I know in prototype read/write: `read(struct file *fp, char *ch, size_t count, loff_t *lofft)` count refers to number of bytes read/write request. But what is the last parameter offset used for and what are the checks needs to be made for offset?

3) For multiple read calls like `cat /dev/chardriver` will the offset be incremented for each read? Like 1st read call offset from 1 to 100 for count=100, in next read call will the offset go from 101? Or will it go from any random number?

Here is my code:

```
    #include <linux/module.h>
    #include <linux/kernel.h>
    #include <linux/fs.h>
    #include <linux/cdev.h>
    #include <linux/device.h>
    #include <linux/uaccess.h>

    static int device_open(struct inode *, struct file *);
    static int device_release(struct inode *, struct file *);
    static ssize_t device_read(struct file *, char *, size_t, loff_t *);
    static ssize_t device_write(struct file *, const char *, size_t, loff_t *);
    char kernelbuff[1024];

    MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

    struct file_operations fops = {
    .read = device_read,
    .write = device_write,
    .open = device_open,
    .release = device_release
    };


    int device_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *fp)
    {
    printk("device_open called");
    return 0;
    }

    static int device_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *fp)
    {
    printk("device_release called");
    return 0;
    }

    static ssize_t device_read(struct file *fp, char *ch, size_t sz, loff_t *lofft)
    {
    printk("device_read called");      
    copy_to_user(ch, kernelbuff, 1024);
    return sz;
    }

    static ssize_t device_write(struct file *fp, const char *ch, size_t sz, loff_t *lofft)
    {
    printk("device_write called");
    copy_from_user(kernelbuff, ch, 50);
    return 1024;
    }

    static int hello_init(void)
    {
      printk("basicchardriver: module initialized");
      register_chrdev(500, "chr_device", &fops);
      return 0;
    }

    static void hello_exit(void)
    {
      printk("basicchardriver: module exited");
      unregister_chrdev(500, "chr_device");
    }

    module_init(hello_init);
    module_exit(hello_exit);
 }
```

To test:

```
sudo mknod -m 666 /dev/chardev c 500 0
echo "Hello World" >> /dev/chardev    ===> Works fine
cat /dev/chardev     ===> Goes to infinite loop
```

If i call the driver using a C program it gives SEG fault:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
  int fd;
  char buff[500];

  fd = open("/dev/chardev", O_RDWR);
  write(fd, "Hello World", 13);

  read(fd, buff, 500);
  printf("Reading data from kernel: \t");
  puts(buff);

  return 0;
}

raj@raj-VirtualBox:~/device-driver/chardriver/read-write$ ./a.out
Reading data from kernel: Hello World
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: `return 1024;` ? `copy_to_user(ch, kernelbuff, 1024);` ? Where from do you take those `1024` and `50` values? `"Hello World"` is 12 characters, not 13. `will the offset be incremented for each read?` no, user passes offset with `pwrite` and `pread`.

Comment: @KamilCuk 1024 is the size of kernel buffer `char kernelbuff[1024];` 50 i hardcoded as the max size of the write "Hello World" or any text i presume should not be more than 50 characters.

Comment: But you can't know that user will want to write 1024 bytes. User wants to write `size_t sz` bytes, not more.

Comment: @KamilCuk True, that was basically customized to fit the C code or the echo i send from command prompt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error checking in a '.read' function in kernel module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33423312/error-checking-in-a-read-function-in-kernel-module)

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks. Yes, it does. I just edited and added the link to my existing answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think i got the correct answer to my question: **(experts please feel free to add your own answers /modify)**

Here is the proper read which works:

```
static ssize_t device_read(struct file *fp, char *ch, size_t sz, loff_t *lofft)
{
        printk("device_read called");
        if (*lofft > 1024 || sz > 1024) 
        {
          return -EFBIF; // return 0 also works
        }
        if ((*lofft+sz) > 1024)
        {
           sz = 1024 - *lofft;
        }

        copy_to_user(ch, kernelbuff + *lofft, sz);
        *lofft+=sz;
        return sz;
}
```

(write operations code is below).

The answers to offset can be referred from here: [Understanding loff_t *offp for file_operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713112/understanding-loff-t-offp-for-file-operations?rq=1)

Some important points regarding offset:

1. So, yes the offset of every consecutive read call needs to be
   adjusted in the read function.
2. The next read offset should start from last_offset +
   count_of_no_of_bytes_read_in_last_function_call
3. Read should return 0, if the offset exceeds the size of kernel
       buffer.

Edited:
The valid checkings needed for read can be referred in this link (suggested by @Tsyvarev): [Error checking in a '.read' function in kernel module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33423312/error-checking-in-a-read-function-in-kernel-module)

Edit: Adding the improved version of write function

```
static ssize_t device_write(struct file *fp, const char *ch, size_t sz, loff_t *lofft)
{
        printk("device_write called");
        if (((*lofft) > sizeof(kernelbuff)) || (sz > sizeof(kernelbuff)))
        {
        printk("Error: Allocating more than kernel buffer size"); // pr_err( ) can also be used as pointed by @KamilCuk
        return -EFBIG;
        }
        if ((*lofft + sz) > sizeof(kernelbuff))
        {
        printk("Error: Allocating more than kernel buffer size");
        return -EFBIG;
        }

        copy_from_user(kernelbuff + *lofft, ch, sz);
        *lofft+=sz;
        return sz;
}
```

Comment: Well, that looks fine, but I would `if (*lofft > 1024) return -EFBIG` exit with hard error in case of errors. Och it should return 0? Also real code should handle `sz + *lofft` addition overflow.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks i corrected it. Not sure of the correct way to handle the addition overflow. You might help to suggest.

Comment: Well, here I would just go with `if (*lofft > 1024 || sz > 1024) return -EFBIF` - that way you know both will be always lower then 1024 ; ) I think just `if (((size_t)*lofft + sz) < sz) return -EFBIF` - addition has to be always greater then both operands and `size_t` is unsigned so it's safe to do a post-addition check.

Comment: @KamilCuk Also added the improved version of write. Please let me know if you have any comments or any further boundary checks needs to be added. Thanks.

Comment: `, 50);` - why 50? `printk("Error:` would be `pr_err("msg")`

Comment: @KamilCuk A copy-paste error, i just changed it. Thanks. The program works perfect if i do an echo and cat. But the C program puts fails to print anything. Wondering why.

Comment: I guess you did `puts("Hello world")`, did you `fflush` or disabled buffering `setvbuf`?

Comment: @KamilCuk So in the file_operation release i need to do a memset of old kernelbuffer? I also observed that the C program keeps printing the old value echoed to the kernel-buffer when i tested using ` cat` and `echo`

Comment: Well... if you don't, no one will do it for you. It really depends on what functionality you want this  module to have.